# Show error message when record is duplicate in my sale order line of openerp

Tags: odoo

What should i do to show error message in `openerp` when there is a duplicate line in sale order line record?

I can't get any way to test it in my project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def action_confirm(self, cr, uid, ids, context=None):

move_obj = self.pool.get('stock.move')

for procurement in self.browse(cr, uid, ids, context=context): 


    cr.execute("select id,order_id,foc from sale_order_line where product_id = %s and order_id= %s and foc = %s", (procurement.product_id.id, procurement.move_id.sale_line_id.order_id.id, procurement.foc,))
    data = cr.fetchall()
    count = len(data)                     

    if count >= 2:
        raise osv.except_osv(_('Data Duplicate!'),
                                  _('Please check the sale order line.Duplicate
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use _sql_constraints

This e.g is from account_payment:

```
_sql_constraints = [
    ('name_uniq', 'UNIQUE(name)', 'The payment line name must be unique!'),
]
```

Hope this will help you.

Regards,

Answer (score 1):

You should create a module that extends the sale.order.line model and adds the constraint that checks for the duplicate. You can find further information here:

https://doc.openerp.com/v6.1/developer/03_modules_2/

Answer (score 1):

You can display the warning message using `osv` package,

```
if True:
   raise osv.except_osv(_('Warning!'),_('You cannot delete a leave'))
```